# does mysql 5.4 has a linux 32 bit version?

Tags: mysql, linux

Can MySQL 5.4 beta be compiled for 32-bit processors under Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The current beta only has binaries for some 64-bit versions, but if you're keen on starting to beta test right now you should be able to compile from the sources on a 32-bit systems. (It IS a beta, of course, so unreliability IS to be expected -- don't run it in production, whether on 32-bit or 64-bit systems!)

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog it's only available for 64-bit machines.

http://willysr.blogspot.com/2009/04/mysql-54-preview.html

or here

> First, the preview release of MySQL
>   5.4 only includes the InnoDB scalability fixes (addressing more
>   CPU's/cores). Second, it is limited to
>   the Solaris and Linux 64-bit platforms
>   at this time. The other features
>   mentioned in this article and
>   additional platform support will be
>   appearing very shortly, so be looking
>   for upcoming announcements soon.
>   http://74.125.93.132/search?q=cache:iLgUTcXAmGUJ:mirror.facebook.com/mysql/tech-resources/articles/mysql-54.html+mysql+5.4+64bit+only&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

google cache because that website is down

Answer (score 0):

if you can run `./configure` and `make` without any errors, it should work properly.